# iOS FirebaseCloudMessaging Notifications not working in Debug / Test Flight nor Release

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I have the notifications working in android without any issue**, but in iOS I can't figure out what seems to be the problem.

- I have created the APN file and upload into Firebase iOS Configuration
- Both Team ID & App ID are correct - double checked
- The "Push Notifications" is both active in the Apple Developer & Xcode
- When the App starts a request by iOS is made to allow notifications

I'm using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin and in my `main.dart` I put:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (Platform.isIOS)
      this.fbaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
            IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true),
      );
}
```

And when the user logs in I grab the token:

```
fbaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
    // Updates the user account
});
```

I have tested in Xcode Simulator, in a iOS device in TestFlight as well as in a released version and I never receive any notification and I have no clue how to debug where is the problem.

Followed several tutorials like:

1. https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=450&v=PzjxZsz3Tjk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved**.

All I had to do was changing this:

```
if (Platform.isIOS)
{
  this.fbaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true),
  );
}
```

To this:

```
if (Platform.isIOS)
{
  this.fbaseMessaging.configure();
  this.fbaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true),
  );
}
```

Seems like even though I don't use the `onResume`, `onLaunch` & `onMessage` the `configure` method has to be called.

Comment: Thanks for this, has struggled with this for 3 days and was redoing the official steps over and over. When I saw your fix I thought, nah this guy must be smoking something, surely this should be in the official documentation, but it worked! A huge thanks!

Comment: @Linesofcode,@Robert Benedetto,anyone help me to resolve this issue.I am not getting notification when app is in background from API.From Firebase Console its working.Can you please send a son format.

Comment: @ShangariC did you resolve it? im facing the same problem

Comment: hello, i have the configure with onmessage and onresume and everything, and the notifications still doesnt work in ios-relase mode but works fine in everything else.

Comment: @azheen Did you find solution? I am having the exact same issue. Notification works fine in debug but doesn't work in release mode

Comment: @azheen I'm facing same issue. how did you fix that?